How to upload pictures with Strapi and create a relation between custom content types and users?
I'm working on a project using Strapi as the backend CMS, and I have three main collections: User (used for authentication), Table1 (which contains a lot of fields and is associated with user actions), and Table2 (used to store pictures). My objectives are to upload pictures to Table2 and create a relation between Table1 and User.
I have set up Strapi with the default authentication for users and created the content types for Table1 and Table2 using the Strapi Content-Type Builder. However, I'm unsure how to configure Strapi to upload and manage pictures in Table2 and how to establish a relationship between Table1 and User so that each entry in Table1 is associated with a user.
So far, I have:

Set up Strapi with user authentication.
Created the content types for Table1 and Table2 using the Strapi Content-Type Builder.
I was expecting to find a clear method to upload images to Table2 and define relations between Table1 and User, but I'm having trouble figuring out the correct approach. Any detailed steps or examples for achieving these tasks would be extremely helpful.

